# Spring 4.1 @Qualifier doesnt'work

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have classes, xml configuration file and error stack trace like this. I have no idea why @Qualifier doesn't work. I see on errors that he don't even do anything.

DOG

```
public class SimpleDog implements Dog {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("small")
    private Size size;
    private String name;

public Size getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(Size size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void giveSound() {
    System.out.println("dog size is : width : (" + size.getWidth() + ") , height : (" + size.getHeight() + ")");
    System.out.println("dog's name : " + name);
}
```

}

TEST CLASS

```
public class Test2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-test2.xml");
    SimpleDog dog = (SimpleDog) context.getBean("dog");
    dog.giveSound();
}
```

}

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dog" class="com.tests.test2.SimpleDog">
         <property name="name" value="Puppy" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="size1" class="com.tests.test2.Size">
        <qualifier value="small"/>
        <property name="height" value="2"/>
        <property name="width" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="size2" class="com.tests.test2.Size">
        <qualifier value="large"/>
        <property name="height" value="20"/>
        <property name="width" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

Error Stack Trace

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dog': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tests.test2.Size com.tests.test2.SimpleDog.size; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tests.test2.Size] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: size1,size2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at pl.patrykgryta.test2.Test2.main(Test2.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tests.test2.Size com.tests.test2.SimpleDog.size; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tests.test2.Size] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: size1,size2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tests.test2.Size] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: size1,size2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 20 more

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dog': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tests.test2.Size com.tests.test2.SimpleDog.size; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tests.test2.Size] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: size1,size2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at pl.patrykgryta.test2.Test2.main(Test2.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tests.test2.Size com.tests.test2.SimpleDog.size; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tests.test2.Size] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: size1,size2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tests.test2.Size] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: size1,size2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 20 more
```

Need help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Qualifier is used to reference a bean by its name or id. Since it can't find an xml entry that has a name or id of 'small' it tries to match by type, of which it found two instances of Size.

The following would work:

```
  <bean id="small" class="com.tests.test2.Size">      
    <property name="height" value="2"/>
    <property name="width" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Though it appears you would like to treat instances of Size as pre-configured beans. If that were the case you could declare instances of Dog in your xml file and refer to Size beans ... something like this:

```
  <bean id="rex" class="com.tests.test2.SimpleDog">
     <property name="name" value="Puppy" />
     <property name="size" ref="size1"/>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 10):

Probably your `ApplicationContext`'s `BeanFactory` is configured with **default** `AutowireCandidateResolver` (i.e. `SimpleAutowireCandidateResolver`) instead of `QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver`.

In previous versions of **Spring** (before 4.0), `QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver` **was** set during creation of most ApplicationContexts (compare `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.customizeBeanFactory(DefaultListableBeanFactory)` implementations).

Currently, `QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver` for AppCtx is/can be applied by:

1. **`org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.CustomAutowireConfigurer`** (see javadoc and implementation of `postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)` method), e.g. add to your xml:

   ```
   <bean id="customAutowireConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.CustomAutowireConfigurer">
   <property name="customQualifierTypes">
       <set>
           <value>org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier</value>
       </set>
   </property>
   ```
2. **`<context:annotation-config />`** (see: `AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parse(Element,ParserContext)` and related)

Comment: Excellent - very helpful for my port from 3.2 to 4.3. Since my @Autowire was already being detected (but failing since Qualifier was not being processed), I didn't need to add the <annotation-config> element.

Comment: This is answer!

Answer (score 2):

@Qualifier(name="..") annotation and give the name of the bean that we want Spring to inject

and name of your beans are size1 and size2 .

so try

```
   @Qualifier("size1")
```

Answer (score 2):

@Qualifier("small") means you look for a bean named "small" (bean id="small" ...) @Autowired means you look for a bean with a type that matchs.

It makes sense to use this two configurations together in some cases. It means: look for a bean named like that, and if you don't find, then look for a bean with the correct type. This can be powerful, very.

From the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html), you can declare who is "small" with an xml qualifier, as you did. But in their example there is NO id="..." I don't know if it makes sense to define both qualifier and id. So I suppose (I don't test) you can repair your example by removing the parts id="sizeX"

Answer (score 1):

As says your stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tests.test2.Size] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: size1,size2
```

Spring can't match a single bean to inject because he find 2 beans that could using, for this reason will thrown this exception.

> Exception thrown when a BeanFactory is asked for a bean instance for
>   which multiple matching candidates have been found when only one
>   matching bean was expected.

[Reference of Exception](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.html)

Anyway you're using this thing in the wrong way, because there isn't any bean with `id="small"`

You must change `@Qualifier("small")` to  `@Qualifier("size1")` or  `@Qualifier("size2")`.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring 4.x you should work with the following XML schema in order for this to work for you:

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"
```

and you should add the following tag:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tests.test2" />
```

So the following XML should solve your problem (it solved mine :) ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tests.test2" />

    <bean id="dog" class="com.tests.test2.SimpleDog">
       <property name="name" value="Puppy" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="size1" class="com.tests.test2.Size">
        <qualifier value="small"/>
        <property name="height" value="2"/>
        <property name="width" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="size2" class="com.tests.test2.Size">
        <qualifier value="large"/>
        <property name="height" value="20"/>
        <property name="width" value="10"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

See more [here](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-beans-auto-wiring-using-autowired-qualifier-resource-annotations-configuration/).

Answer (score 0):

We have struts 1.x used with Spring 3.x in our project. In the process of upgrading from spring 3->4, our qualifier annotation in the struts action does not work any more. After digging in and compare the Spring 3 and 4, finally found the reason.

**reason1: QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver is not the default resolver in spring 4**

In Spring 3, after we create our beanfacotry in the application context, Spring will explicitly call :

```
beanFactory.setAutowireCandidateResolver(new QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver());
```

In spring 4, it is not called any more in the AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext’s

```
protected void customizeBeanFactory(DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
```

So for the parent(root) context, it should still work as is if you have the  in the config xml. However for the child context the default resolver will become ‘SimpleAutowireCandidateResolver’

**reason2: The child resolver is passed to parent when trying to determine ‘isAutowireCandidate()’ in Spring 4’s DefaultListableBeanFactory**

The isAutowireCandidate() will delegate the responsibility to parent beanFactory if it cannot make decision.

In Spring 3, the delegation does not pass the resolver to the parent so that parent context uses its own resolver to call the isAutowireCandidate(). However in Spring 4, it changes. The resolver is passed as a parameter to the parent who uses it to call the isAutowireCandidate(). So even the parent has a ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver which extends QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver as its resolver, it still does not help.

The @a5phyx solution should work if it is added to the ***child***'s application context xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this bean definition in your beans.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- define your beans here-->
</beans>
```

Comment: You should aways explain your answer. _Why_ should someone try this? What part of your answer fixes the problem?

Comment: Sure @PatrickQ.  <context:annotation-config/> fixes the problem, but for making   <context:annotation-config/> to work, we need to include the name space as done in the above code using "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"