# Configure App. context to use QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver using annotations

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-annotations, spring-4

The problem started when in **Spring 4.2.5** I attempted to inject an interface having more than one implementations, below is the test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = VenueConfig.class)
public class BandEventTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("rush")
    Band rush;

    @Autowired
    Venue venue;

    @Test
    public void assertBandNotNull() {
        Assert.assertNotNull("Who will perform if there's no band !!!", rush);
    }

    @Test
    public void assertVenueNotNull() {
        Assert.assertNotNull("Without venue, there would be no event !!!", venue);
    }

    @Test
    public void triggerEvent() {
        venue.hostPerformance();
    }
}
```

I have the interface Band which is implemented by two beans viz. Rush and VanHalen :

```
@Component("rush")
public class Rush implements Band {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.book.springinaction.chap2.autowiring.Band#play()
     */
    public void play() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Rush playing 'Limelight'");
    }

}
```

In spite of using the Qualifier annotation(please ignore the lower/upper case current Qualifier name and the Rush bean name, I have tried all the combinations in vain). My suspicion was confirmed after I [read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426694/spring-4-1-qualifier-doesntwork) about the QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver not being set in App. context since Spring 4.0

I wish to fit the below (mentioned even in the Spring documentation) :

```
<bean id="customAutowireConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.CustomAutowireConfigurer">
    <property name="customQualifierTypes">
        <set>
            <value>org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier</value>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

in my below Configuration class **WITHOUT XML i.e JUST ANNOTATIONS**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class VenueConfig {

    /*Does using @Bean for CustomAutowireConfigurer make sense ?*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Spring annotations, but your pointer to the other thread was so helpful that I did a bit of research. Based on [the Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-basic-concepts), I believe you can have the same effect with:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class VenueConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomAutowireConfigurer qualifierAutowireConfigurer() {
      CustomAutowireConfigurer customAutowireConfig = new CustomAutowireConfigurer();
      customAutowireConfig.setCustomQualifierTypes( Collections.singleton( Qualifier.class ));
      return customAutowireConfig;
    }
}
```