# Ambiguous autowiring but none with qualifier

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have a service, which injects a `Bean` with `@Autowired` as follows.

```
@Service
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService {
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate adminServiceTemplate;
}
```

And an xml that holds two beans, causing ambiguous autowiring

```
<bean id="serviceWebClient" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
<!-- More properties -->
</bean>

<bean id="adminServiceWebClient" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
<!-- More properties -->
</bean>
```

This obviously causes the following exception *(at startup)*:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: serviceWebClient,adminServiceWebClient
```

**The weird part:**

When I add the `@Qualifier` in my service to specify which `Bean` to select, it suddenly can't find any anymore. E.g. I edit my service to the following:

```
@Service
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("adminServiceWebClient")
    private WebServiceTemplate adminServiceTemplate;
}
```

And instead of getting my specified `Bean`, I get the following exception message *(at a later time when I retrieve the `ApplicationContext` with `context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG_FILE);`)*:

```
 No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Is there any logical explanation of something this odd happening? I'm not even sure where to start debugging. It seems to find both, but still refuses to `autowire` one.

**Edit**

When removing the additional `Bean` from my `XML` and the `@Qualifier` annotation, I **still** get:

```
 No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

But it works fine at startup. It just fails after calling:

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG_FILE);
```

So at startup it seems to find it (it's required and doesn't fail), but it fails when requesting the context.

Comment: Does `WebServiceTemplate` implement a interface?

Comment: @dambros It implements `WebServiceOperations`, but it's a `Spring` maintained class for sending `SOAP` messages. It shouldn't matter much normally.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't replicate the problem here. I tried using Spring boot but as soon as I add the qualifier, it works.

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26775786/1421925. You could be using the wrong autowire candidate resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out why this problem occurred. And it was a (rather stupid) mistake. In case someone else also runs into this, check out the following:

#### Overview

I run my application with various `Spring Bean` files. When my application starts, I use a "main context" file which does a `component-scan` of my entire base-package. Inside this "main" file I have the `WebServiceTemplate Beans`.

#### Startup

My `component-scan` finds my `service` and autowires its respectful `WebServiceTemplate Bean` into it. So it works fine at startup, as expected.

#### Runtime

When I call

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG_FILE);
```

I actually call a **different** file. This file does **not** contain the `WebServiceTemplate Beans` but it **did** also contain a `component-scan` of the entire base-package. Causing it to find my `Service`, but not the beans it should autowire.

#### Solution

When loading the other file, I changed the `component-scan` to be more narrowed down to just what I need. So it doesn't scan for the service, but it gets loaded at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are actually starting two application contexts? One would have those beans present while the other wouldn't.

If this is the case, your first context would start okay when the qualifier is present but second one would fail due to the beans missing (exception #2). With no qualifier present, first context would fail to start due to two alternates.

To solve this (when starting second context) give it a parent context:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{CONFIG_LOCATION}, parentContext);
```

Comment: That actually was my problem, I was writing my answer while you posted this. Thanks for the help! (+1)