# Springs @Qualifier annotation not working

Tags: spring

Am playing around with `@Qualifier` along with `@Autowired`.
Here is my application context file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="helloBean" class="com.springex1.HelloWorld1">
    <property name="name" value="Mkyong" />
</bean>

<bean id="address1" class="com.springex1.Address" >
    <property name="street" value="sahajanand" />
</bean>

<bean id="address2" class="com.springex1.Address" >
    <property name="street" value="pune" />
</bean>
```

Here are my Java classes
HelloWorld1.java

```
package com.springex1;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class HelloWorld1 {
private String name;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("address1")
private Address address = null; 

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public void printHelloWithAddress() {
    System.out.println("Hello ! " + name + " your street " + address.getStreet());
}


}
```

Address.java

```
package com.springex1;

public class Address {
private String street = "";

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getStreet(){
    return this.street;
}
}
```

Here is where I am trying to get things to run - App.java

```
package com.springex1;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    call1("appContext1.xml");           
}

public static void call1(String appContext){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(appContext);

    HelloWorld1 obj = (HelloWorld1) context.getBean("helloBean");
    obj.printHelloWithAddress();
}     
}
```

I keep getting this exception -ideally I should not since I have the @Qualifier annotation with the id 'address1' defined - so it should not throw an exception

> WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'address': No qualifying bean of type [com.springex1.Address] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: address1,address2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.springex1.Address] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: address1,address2
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'address': No qualifying bean of type [com.springex1.Address] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: address1,address2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.springex1.Address] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: address1,address2
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)

I am using spring 4.3 release version - this is the only dependency in my pom

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
 -->
```

Comment: This should help you solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26775786/1291150

Comment: yes I did see this link previously - infact in the link you provide - there are two answers - by 'Neelam Mehta' and 'mcoolive' that specify exactly what I have done and yet it did not work for me - the answer that is accepted says '@Qualifier is used to reference a bean by its name or id. Since it can't find an xml entry that has a name or id of 'small' it tries to match by type, of which it found two instances of Size.' and in my case I am referring to the bean by its id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `<context:annotation-config />` to the configuration xml to resolve the @Qualifier annotation, you can find the updated xml below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="helloBean" class="com.code.samples.HelloWorld1">
    <property name="name" value="Mkyong" />
</bean>

<bean id="address1" class="com.code.samples.Address" >
    <property name="street" value="sahajanand" />
</bean>

<bean id="address2" class="com.code.samples.Address" >
    <property name="street" value="pune" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: yes this worked - but I thought the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor definition is enough - apparently it is not - wonder why ?

Comment: <context:annotation-config> is needed to activate annotations in beans registered through XML

Answer (score 1):

First, it is recommended by Spring docs not to use the `@Qualifier` and instead of it's recommended to use the `@Resource` annotation which do its injecting by name (like a qualifier).

So option one is to replace the `@Qualifier` with `@Resource` annotation.

But in order IOC will do its injecting properly using `@Resource` you should

name `Address address` 
to `Address address1`

Now, if you still want to use `@Qualifier` you'll have to change your configuration to:

```
<bean id="address1" class="com.springex1.Address" >
    <property name="street" value="sahajanand" />
    <qualifier value="address1"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks - will read more about Resource .Regarding Qualifier - I thought this should be enough - @Qualifier("address1") and in the app context  I have it defined as - <bean id="address1" class="com.springex1.Address" >

Answer (score 0):

Spring 4.x uses the following bean schema:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
```

You also need to add:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

or:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.package" />
```

By adding one of these tags you can remove the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor definition from the xml.